# Does firestore rules validate every time when data receive?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Does firestore rules validate every time when data receive? Or only when the listener create?

Data structure

```
- users
  - user1
    isAllowToReadMessage: true

- messages
  - message1
    content: "Hello"
  - message2
    content: "How are you doing"
```

And rules

```
match /messages/{messageId} {
   allow list: get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).isAllowToReadMessage;
}
```

Let's say a user add a listener on `/messages`, But if `isAllowToReadMessage` changed to false after the listener added, Will user still receive newest message?

```
_profileRepository.collection("messages")
            .doc(_firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid)
            .snapshots()
            .listen((snapshot) {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's say a user adds a listener on `/messages`. But if
> `isAllowToReadMessage` changes to false after the listener is added,
> will the user still receive newest messages?

The answer is **NO**: The user will stop receiving messages if the Security Rules change in such a way they prevent him/her from reading the docs of the collection.

---

In addition note that there is an error in your security rule syntax. You should use the [`data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource?authuser=0&hl=en#data) property as follows:

```
match /messages/{messageId} {
   allow list: get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAllowToReadMessage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to point me out wrong syntax and word, I edited my answer, And this seems the `get` get call every time when a new message receive?

Comment: Please do not edit your question with the proposed corrections: Other SO users reading the question may not understand the answer anymore. To answer your question: Each time the content of your `messages` collection change, the listener that you set with `snapshots().listen((snapshot) {});` makes a call in order to update the query snapshot. This call is evaluated against your security rules.